# C# How to iterate throught all the lists in child's list?

Tags: c#, list, loops, dialog, infinite

so I've stopped to this problem which solution I can't think of, it currently escapes my mind althought I think I did this same thing on another project, but I lost the files..

Thing is, I'm writting a dialogue system that has one answer line, and up to 3 question lines, each of these question lines, when clicked, have another answer line and can have even more questions to be made.

The goal is to be able to make a dialogue system that can have as much answers and questions in line as you want.

But I don't know how to iterate them all, if it was a fixed number, I could make a for loop for each number of questions, but it not being the case, I'm stuck on it!

The following code is an example of a fixed number of ONE question and its answer and another list of questions:

```
for(int i = 0; i < dialogGiver.dialogLines.Count; i++)
{
    EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Line " + i, EditorStyles.boldLabel);

    dialogGiver.dialogLines[i].line = EditorGUILayout.TextField("Question", dialogGiver.dialogLines[i].line);
    dialogGiver.dialogLines[i].answer = EditorGUILayout.TextField("Answer", dialogGiver.dialogLines[i].answer);

    for (int e = 0; e < dialogGiver.dialogLines[i].dialogLines.Count; e++)
    {
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Line " + i + "/ Line " + e, EditorStyles.boldLabel);
    }
}
```

So thing is, how do I make that loop look for as much sub-questions and sub-lines as the DialogLine (and the DialogLine childs into that DialogLine) has.

This is the DialogLine class:

```
public class DialogLine
{
    public string line;
    public string answer;

    /// <summary>
    /// This will enable the dialog giver to continue speaking of the same theme (use for long dialogs!)
    /// </summary>
    public List<DialogLine> dialogLines = new List<DialogLine>();
}
```

Thanks in advance, I'm willing to learn how should this work!

Comment: Use ForEach instead of for, problem solved.

Comment: Just add a link to the subs inside the wrapper.
So you can check if it has a sub, then iterate over it again. You can do this recursively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    public void RecursiveMethod(List<DialogLine> list)
    {
         for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
         {
               EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Line " + i, EditorStyles.boldLabel);

               list[i].line = EditorGUILayout.TextField("Question", list[i].line);
               list[i].answer = EditorGUILayout.TextField("Answer", list[i].answer);
               RecursiveMethod(list[i].dialogLines);
         }
    }
```

Made this quite fast. But it should be something like this. It will keep iterating through all childs, till it encounters an empty list ofcourse.

Goodluck!

Comment: Hey! Thanks for that fast comment! I totally got the idea althought I used the example shown by @C Sharper :D

Comment: That you prefer to be spoonfed instead of pointed in the right direction.

Comment: I actually ended up using your example tho

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :) I hate brain***** too

Answer (score 0):

Create a additonal property to determine if there is any child `Dialogline`.
Now you could work with recursion: (not tested)

```
public List<DialogLine> GetAllDialogLines(DialogLine rootDialogLine)
{
   List<DialogLine> allLines = new List<DialogLine>();

   if(rootDialogLone.HasChilds)
   {
      GetAllDialogLines(rootDialogLine, allLines);
   }
   else
   {
      allLines.Add(rootDialogLine);
   }

   return allLines;
}

private void GetAllDialogLines(List<DialogLine> dialogLines, List<DialogLine> result)
{

   foreach(var dl in  dialogLines)
   {
      result.Add(dl); 

   if(dl.HasChilds)
   {
       GetAllDialogLines(dl, result);
   }
   }  
}


public class DialogLine
{
    public string line;
    public string answer;

    public bool HasChilds
    {
         get {return dialogLines.count > 0;}
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This will enable the dialog giver to continue speaking of the same theme (use for long dialogs!)
    /// </summary>
    public List<DialogLine> dialogLines = new List<DialogLine>();
}
```

Comment: Just great man, and thanks for the quick response, I totally got back on track ^^